# non zero linear functional and which of the following statements are true. (NBHM-$2014$)

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $V$ be finite dimensional real vector space and let $f$ and $g$ be non zero linear functionals on $V$.  Assume that $\ker(f) \subset \ker(g).$ Which of the following are true??

a. $\ker(f)=\ker(g)$

b. $f=\lambda g$ for some real number $\lambda \ne 0$.

c. The linear map $A\colon V\to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $Ax=(f(x),g(x))$ for all $x \in V$, is onto.

Since $\ker(f)\subset \ker(g)$ we get $\ker(f)=\ker(g)$ and hence (a) and (b) are true. Now the linear map will look like $Ax=(\lambda g(x),g(x))$ . I guess (c) will be false. Not sure though.

Comment: If (b) is true, then $Ax=\lambda (g(x),g(x))$. It looks like the range of $A$ is the diagonal.

Comment: @Siminore Then? What does it imply?

Comment: Question (c) asks you if the range of $A$ is the whole of $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you are allowed to use (b), then the range of $A$ has dimension one.

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam : You got it?? :O No responce only acceptance?? :P

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik c is false.. since dimension is $1$ but that of $R^2$ is $2$

Comment: ok ok.... i am not at all using that statement anyway...

Answer (score 4):

I am sure first two thirds of this question has been discussed hee already..

Coming to third part I would go for a very basic example of linear map :

$f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=x;g(x)=2x$

This should conclude $c$ is True/False??

Answer (score 3):

(a) Correct. (a) follows from the rank nullity theorem.

(b) Correct. (b) follows from (a), the fact that $\mathrm{im}f = \mathrm{im}g$ and the fact that linear maps $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ must be of the form $x \mapsto \lambda x$.

(c) does not hold. For a counterexample let $V=\mathbb R^3$, $f(x)=g(x)=p_x$ the projection onto the $x$-axis. Then the point $(1,2)$ is not in the image of $A$.